# Proper implementation of stack-like structure in ST Monad

Tags: haskell

What would be a good (in particular fast) implementation of a stack in an ST Monad like I am used to from imperative languages? I came up with this but I am unsure if there wouldn't be a better or faster solution.

```
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.STRef
import Control.Monad


stackDemo :: [Int] -> [Int]
stackDemo ls = runST $ do
    stack <- newSTRef []

    forM_ ls $ \i -> do
        temp <- readSTRef stack
        let x = 2 * i
        writeSTRef stack (x : temp)     -- push element on stack

    readSTRef stack                     -- read out stack and return it
```

Calling it gives

```
*Main> stackDemo [1 .. 10]
[20,18,16,14,12,10,8,6,4,2]
```

At the end I just want a function keeping referential transparency and use a fast stack at some place in its code.

Comment: This is probably slower than passing around the list in a pure context... This stack is a list, plus one indirection for the `STRef`.

Comment: `stackDemo = reverse . map (*2)` would be faster

Comment: @4castle Used this example for demonstration purpose.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia But is it fast in the ST Monad context?

Comment: If you have only one stack ref, and no other refs around, using `ST` is overkill -- use a `State [Int]` monad instead. If you need `ST` for other refs, then it might be a reasonable choice. It should be roughly as efficient as passing/returning a `[Int]` in non-monadic code.